# ECT control/sensor on 2001 Chevy Monte Carlo location

Tags: electrical, chevrolet

Where exactly is the ECT sensor/control located on 2001 Chevy Monte Carlo?

Answer (score 2):

The connector for it is #8 so it puts it at the front drivers side of the engine if I'm looking at this diagram correctly.

[image]